# Integrate Azure Functions with Event Hub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-functions

I've created a Azure function from EventHub-trigger template. But I've stuck with two issues:

a) How to specify the consumer group other than default?

b) Is there any way to get whole EventData object rather than just the message string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: Consumer Group can now be specified in the portal as well (issue mentioned below has been fixed).

For your first question, we have an issue tracking that and we'll get to it soon (repo issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/704)).

For your second question, I'm assuming you're starting from our C# template, which uses string, but you can change that to `EventData` (where the name of the parameter "evt" matches the name you chose in your binding):

```
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"

using System;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

public static void Run(EventData evt, TraceWriter log)
{
    var id = evt.Properties["id"];
    log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed event: {id}");
}
```

See the EventHub wiki page [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support) for more information on possible bindings. You can bind in many other ways as well, for example your own POCO class, an array of events, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
But the signature must be the following, otherwise compilation fails.

public static void Run(EventData myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)

Comment: Well, the name of the actual parameter varies - it's up to you when you set your function. My function used "evt" as the param name. I'll clarify my example above.